# C# Oracle transactions

Tags: c#, oracle

How can I insert a record a their childs in a single transaction?

For example I have a class named `Requisition` (`IdRequisition`, `Description`, `RegisterDate`) and `RequisitionRequirement` (`IdRequisitionRequirement`, `IdRequisition`, `DocumentName`, `DeliveryDate`, `LimitDate`) and I need to insert the `Requisition` and get the `IdRequisition` by outparameter and then insert the list of `RequisitionRequirements` that must being related with the `Requisition`, in a single transaction and ensure that if one of the `RequisitionRequirement` fails the insert, do a rollback.

I don't know what is the correct form to do it, if handling transactions from c# with `cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction()` or another way.

I was using Linq to entities and we had no problem with that, but the current app uses Oracle and stored procedures and I'am new in this context.

Sorry for my english but I'm learning too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your code in a transaction scope. Do not close the connection while calling the stored procs inside the scope. BTW consider using a function to return the IdRequisition instead of using an out parameter.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Save Requisition and get IdRequisition 
    // Save RequisitionRequirements 
}
```

Comment: don't forget scope.Complete() or you will get auto rolled back!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to open the connection and then retrieve transaction instance by calling `connection.BeginTransaction()` method.

Take a look at ODP.NET article - [Choose the ODP.NET transaction type that fits your business rules.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-may/o39odpnet-087387.html)

Comment: In this case the Requisition is inserted successfully but the RequisitionRequirements are not inserted.